# Change GTK 3 themes to spesific apps causing %f not detected

Tags: gtk, .desktop, gtk3, wps-office

i change my .desktop option for wps, in the exec
from

`Exec=/usr/bin/wps %f`

to

`Exec=sh -c 'GTK_DATA_PREFIX=/usr/share/themes/Ant/gtk-3.0/gtk.css wps %f'`

but the themes not change to Ant, i think it change to Adwaita, and i cant use the %f function, i mean i cant double click the docx file directly from the exploler because the path where i save the file contain a space character

Answer (score 0):

To handle filenames with space, put `%f` between quotations

```
Exec=sh -c 'GTK_DATA_PREFIX=/usr/share/themes/Ant/gtk-3.0/gtk.css wps "%f"'
```

Comment: it's doesnt work, the theme didnt change to ant, and i still cant open my docx, then i try  /usr/bin/wps -style gtk+ , it wont work too, says "unable to open gtk+"